# Matter with IIS Express in Win 8.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

i just created a local website last year , and i was using it on windows 7 IIS(express) and it worked correctly for a long time , after switching to windows 8.1 some parts of the website are not working , i donno why!!!!!!!!!
the site is about file browsing , i mean i created this website to access my files localy. and i realized that it is runnig well on visual studio in debugging mode.

here is the error detail :

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01: iisexpress.exe
Problem Signature 02: 8.5.9748.0
Problem Signature 03: 537e7316
Problem Signature 04: App_Web_uw0bxii3
Problem Signature 05: 0.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06: 54f14cb0
Problem Signature 07: 4c
Problem Signature 08: 37b
Problem Signature 09: System.AccessViolationException
OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.4
Locale ID: 1033
Additional Information 1: 8980
Additional Information 2: 8980820270b58dad3b2b2a91edcf775a
Additional Information 3: e2b3
Additional Information 4: e2b3fb42ddbed36d301480f5b1ff1013

Read our privacy statement online: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline: C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

any body has any idea???????

Comment: IIS Express is not IIS. The error log only indicates an `AccessViolationException` was unhandled and therefore crashed the process.

Comment: apologies sir, but it works on windows 7 with same version of IIS express, and even it works on visual studio 2010 on windows 8.1 and 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys after days i found the problem, there was a dll that causes this error, and because of win 8 security it couldnt be used . so i just replaced that dll with another one from .net library and its solved.

Comment: What was the DLL?